# How can I make bable's preset-env not transform async-await statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I've been using babel's preset-env to target my transforms, but I noticed that no matter what I do, it will always transform my async-await statements.

Since I know my browser support allows for async-await (newest Chrome browsers), this both makes my code less performant and noticeably harder to debug.

I've tried both the `shippedProposals` option and `exclude` but it still always transforms it.

Edit 
From looking at the code, it seems like it is actually impossible to blacklist some packages - https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/src/filter-items.js#L69

Basically if something is included in `pluginSyntaxMap` (which is derived from [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/data/shipped-proposals.js#L6)), it will always be included (unless there is a way to override this behavior that I am missing?)

Comment: "Since I know my browser support allows for async-await (newest Chrome browsers)" The point of Babel is to allow support for all major browsers. I don't see the point of using Babel if you are developping for your single platform. "this both makes my code less performant and noticeably harder to debug." You are not supposed to debug the final build directly. You should use proper tools that can exploit sourcemaps if you need to debug your code after the transpiling. Though you are right about performances.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions - async-await is supported by all major browsers. And when I say harder to debug, I mean that step-into is broken on the source-mapped version of async-await transform, and more areas of the code cannot be added to breakpoints. Also - the fact that a specific feature I use doesnt require babel does not mean I do not require babel in my project, neither does it mean I dont want the future proof behavior preset-env provides